# Appending a class variable to a list is overwriting the previous class variables

Tags: python, append

I am having a problem when executing the following Python method:

```
def execute_callback(self, goal_handle):
        self.get_logger().info('Executing goal...')

        # creating the feedback message variable
        feedback_msg = OdomRecord.Feedback()
        feedback_msg.current_total = 0.0

        # creating current_odom var
        curr_odom = Point()

        # ensuring all variables that will be used below are reset
        self.odom_record = []
        self.last_x = 0.0
        self.last_y = 0.0
        self.second_last_x = 0.0
        self.second_last_y = 0.0
        self.total_distance = 0.0

        # storing the first odometry values received (to be used as a reference later)
        self.first_odom.x = self.last_odom.x
        self.first_odom.y = self.last_odom.y

        # storing first measurement in an array of Point values
        self.odom_record.append(self.first_odom)

        # iteration variable will be used to ensure that action server doesn't stop prematurely
        iter = 0

        while True:

            # incrementing the number of iteration
            iter += 1

            # extracting current_odometry message from self.last_odom
            curr_odom.x = self.last_odom.x
            curr_odom.y = self.last_odom.y
            curr_odom.z = self.last_odom.z

            # store current odometry measurement in an array of Point values (IN WHILE LOOP)
            self.odom_record.append(curr_odom)

            # taking the last odometry measurment stored in the odom_record array
            self.last_x = self.odom_record[-1].x
            self.last_y = self.odom_record[-1].y

            # taking the second to last odometry measurment stored in the odom_record array
            self.second_last_x = self.odom_record[-2].x
            self.second_last_y = self.odom_record[-2].y

            # DEBUGGING CODE
            self.get_logger().warn(f'first_odom.x= {self.first_odom.x}')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'first_odom.y= {self.first_odom.y}')
            self.get_logger().warn('------------------------------')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'curr_odom.x= {curr_odom.x}')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'last_x= {self.last_x}')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'second_last_x= {self.second_last_x}')
            self.get_logger().warn('------------------------------')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'curr_odom.y= {curr_odom.y}')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'last_y= {self.last_y}')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'second_last_y= {self.second_last_y}')
            self.get_logger().warn('------------------------------')
            self.get_logger().warn(f'odom_record= {self.odom_record}')

            # computing the distance travelled so far (IN WHILE LOOP)
            self.total_distance = self.total_distance + self.dist_diff([self.last_x, self.last_y],
                                                                       [self.second_last_x, self.second_last_y])
            self.get_logger().warn(
                f"TOTAL DISTANCE= {self.total_distance}")

            # Return as feedback the current value of self.total_distance (IN WHILE LOOP)
            feedback_msg.current_total = self.total_distance
            goal_handle.publish_feedback(feedback_msg)

            # calculating the distance between the initial measurement and the current measurement
            self.first_last_dist = self.dist_diff([self.last_odom.x, self.last_odom.y],
                                                  [self.first_odom.x, self.first_odom.y])

            self.get_logger().info(
                f"DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= {self.first_last_dist}")

            # check if initial position is reached again (iter>5 was added to ensure that the while loop doesn't end prematurely)
            if self.first_last_dist < 0.05 and iter > 5:
                self.get_logger().warn("INITIAL POSITION REACHED!")
                break

            # waiting 1 second before repeating the loop
            time.sleep(1.0)
```

In the code above, the variable `self.last_odom` is of class type `geometry_msgs.msgs.Point()` and it is returning odometry measurements from a robot and it is being updated from another Python method continuously and instantaneously.

So I am trying to extract the odometry measurement in each loop iteration, and storing the measurements in `curr_odom` which is also of class type `geometry_msgs.msgs.Point()`. Then, I am trying to append the current measurements to a list called `odom_record`. Finally, I am taking the last 2 measurements from the list and computing the distance between them. However, it seems that only the first measurement is being stored properly (the measurement stored in the list before entering the while loop) then the remaining values in the list are being overwritten in every iteration, which is preventing the `self.total_distance` variable from being updated.

An example output of the code above is the following

```
user:~/ros2_ws$ ros2 run wall_follower odometry_recording
[INFO] [1677712673.210979499] [odom_rec_action_server]: Executing goal...
[WARN] [1677712673.219165565] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712673.222947662] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712673.227642013] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712673.233086020] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712673.235113921] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712673.236346965] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712673.237562725] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712673.238626609] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712673.282067471] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712673.286728535] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712673.289000192] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712673.291159377] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712673.292474568] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712673.293726157] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.0015668298077918682
[WARN] [1677712674.296198014] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712674.297093371] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712674.298066966] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712674.299029985] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= 0.29476196370334273
[WARN] [1677712674.299904873] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= 0.29476196370334273
[WARN] [1677712674.300994797] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= 0.29476196370334273
[WARN] [1677712674.301963354] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712674.302952278] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.575924627980788
[WARN] [1677712674.304000118] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.575924627980788
[WARN] [1677712674.305024224] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.575924627980788
[WARN] [1677712674.306389597] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712674.307502857] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.29476196370334273, y=0.575924627980788, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.29476196370334273, y=0.575924627980788, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712674.308665926] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712674.315337557] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.050676056323689225
[WARN] [1677712675.317903544] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712675.318957140] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712675.320056173] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712675.320935174] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= 0.23591748404123547
[WARN] [1677712675.322033801] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= 0.23591748404123547
[WARN] [1677712675.323202569] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= 0.23591748404123547
[WARN] [1677712675.324095235] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712675.324944371] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.5865161358277781
[WARN] [1677712675.326009855] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.5865161358277781
[WARN] [1677712675.327037142] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.5865161358277781
[WARN] [1677712675.328057150] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712675.329002061] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.23591748404123547, y=0.5865161358277781, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.23591748404123547, y=0.5865161358277781, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.23591748404123547, y=0.5865161358277781, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712675.329918298] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712675.330782191] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.11046571948995636
[WARN] [1677712676.380778954] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712676.382645582] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712676.384052170] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712676.385112210] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= 0.18681464581179674
[WARN] [1677712676.386509904] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= 0.18681464581179674
[WARN] [1677712676.388045428] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= 0.18681464581179674
[WARN] [1677712676.389213584] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712676.390420609] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.5955353774818314
[WARN] [1677712676.391687589] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.5955353774818314
[WARN] [1677712676.392776397] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.5955353774818314
[WARN] [1677712676.393866374] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712676.397773936] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.18681464581179674, y=0.5955353774818314, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.18681464581179674, y=0.5955353774818314, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.18681464581179674, y=0.5955353774818314, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.18681464581179674, y=0.5955353774818314, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712676.410405474] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712676.414426713] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.16379903802998932
[WARN] [1677712677.481801552] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712677.482671823] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712677.484327064] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712677.486298480] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= 0.13129132305723606
[WARN] [1677712677.488005108] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= 0.13129132305723606
[WARN] [1677712677.489023067] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= 0.13129132305723606
[WARN] [1677712677.490031338] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712677.491511708] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.6057887450086615
[WARN] [1677712677.493195064] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.6057887450086615
[WARN] [1677712677.494991487] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.6057887450086615
[WARN] [1677712677.496693865] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712677.498892001] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.13129132305723606, y=0.6057887450086615, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.13129132305723606, y=0.6057887450086615, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.13129132305723606, y=0.6057887450086615, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.13129132305723606, y=0.6057887450086615, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.13129132305723606, y=0.6057887450086615, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712677.499920664] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712677.503659311] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.2201360520837721
[WARN] [1677712678.506762301] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712678.510399310] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712678.513817574] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712678.581924569] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= 0.07559653565758329
[WARN] [1677712678.582529735] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= 0.07559653565758329
[WARN] [1677712678.583234950] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= 0.07559653565758329
[WARN] [1677712678.587145298] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712678.588283349] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.6162644987578844
[WARN] [1677712678.589340929] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.6162644987578844
[WARN] [1677712678.595961625] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.6162644987578844
[WARN] [1677712678.597108451] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712678.598247693] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.07559653565758329, y=0.6162644987578844, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.07559653565758329, y=0.6162644987578844, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.07559653565758329, y=0.6162644987578844, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.07559653565758329, y=0.6162644987578844, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.07559653565758329, y=0.6162644987578844, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.07559653565758329, y=0.6162644987578844, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712678.599635419] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712678.602943932] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.27683534591433406
[WARN] [1677712679.604334903] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712679.605239180] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712679.612062223] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712679.612929621] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= -0.002641854739749117
[WARN] [1677712679.620241867] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= -0.002641854739749117
[WARN] [1677712679.621349405] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= -0.002641854739749117
[WARN] [1677712679.622420483] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712679.679692502] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.6311744914445333
[WARN] [1677712679.680672209] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.6311744914445333
[WARN] [1677712679.681621039] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.6311744914445333
[WARN] [1677712679.684538107] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712679.685884709] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.002641854739749117, y=0.6311744914445333, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712679.688613928] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
[INFO] [1677712679.689715495] [odom_rec_action_server]: DISTANCE TO INITIAL POSITION= 0.35646722623419397
[WARN] [1677712680.691413674] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.x= 0.3446848931745341
[WARN] [1677712680.692458013] [odom_rec_action_server]: first_odom.y= 0.5672203877763718
[WARN] [1677712680.693675659] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712680.694744606] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.x= -0.07447950333849136
[WARN] [1677712680.696116717] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_x= -0.07447950333849136
[WARN] [1677712680.697261036] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_x= -0.07447950333849136
[WARN] [1677712680.698704705] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712680.699977207] [odom_rec_action_server]: curr_odom.y= 0.6443518838049203
[WARN] [1677712680.701193002] [odom_rec_action_server]: last_y= 0.6443518838049203
[WARN] [1677712680.702386315] [odom_rec_action_server]: second_last_y= 0.6443518838049203
[WARN] [1677712680.703722218] [odom_rec_action_server]: ------------------------------
[WARN] [1677712680.706431498] [odom_rec_action_server]: odom_record= [geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=0.3446848931745341, y=0.5672203877763718, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136,y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0), geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-0.07447950333849136, y=0.6443518838049203, z=0.0)]
[WARN] [1677712680.709506332] [odom_rec_action_server]: TOTAL DISTANCE= 0.0
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `curr_odom` always contains the same `Point` object, so all the elements of `odom_record` are that same object that you keep modifying. You need to move `curr_odom = Point()` into the loop.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much! Can you post your message as an answer so that I can accept it as the solution?

Comment: There's almost certainly dozens of duplicate questions, I just don't have a link to any of them. It's not worth answering again.

Comment: Alright thank you in any case @Barmar.. Sorry I tried to check for a similar question before I created this post but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) in the comments.

> `curr_odom` always contains the same `Point` object, so all the elements of `odom_record` are that same object that you keep modifying. You need to move `curr_odom = Point()` into the loop.

Comment: You should now accept the answer with the checkmark.